# What should be the Table structure for following situation

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where i need to store "Error Type" which has following options

[image]

I want to know what is the best way I should use to create my table "Error".

So either I take a "**VARCHAR**" data type and store values like "1,3,4" (Comma Separated) if "Take Off, Details and Legend" is selected and parse it when getting in view

OR

Take separate column for each field in table with data type "**TINYINT**" like "IsTakeOff" , "IsSpecifications" ,"Details" etc.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user with id 1 select 1,3 and 4 then you can use following

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple columns unless you are very confident the number won't grow.

Otherwise use a many-to-many association table - one with columns for the id of the item and the id of the error

Answer (score 0):

One way to go might be to do it as an int and then in your code do something like this PHP, I don't know language you are using but most languages have a switch so it shouldn't be to hard to translate to another language.

```
$row // The row from the database.
switch ($row['Error_Type'])
{
    case ('0'):
        {
            // Do something.
            break;
        }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma seperated column here that is varchar because you know that no of records will not grow here. And this is limited to only 5 values. And while searching the field you can use MySQL FIND_IN_SET which is very effective for this kind of situations. FIND_IN_SET will take two parameters. Your search keyword and the comma seperated string.